# Create a new list of dicts in common between n lists of dicts?

Tags: python

I have an unknown number of lists of product results as dictionary entries that all have the same keys. I'd like to generate a new list of products that appear in all of the old lists.

'what products are available in all cities?'

given:

```
list1 = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'bat', 'price': 20.00}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'ball', 'price': 12.00}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'brick', 'price': 19.00}]
list2 = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'bat', 'price': 18.00}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'brick', 'price': 11.00}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'ball', 'price': 17.00}]
list3 = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'bat', 'price': 16.00}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'boat', 'price': 10.00}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'brick', 'price': 15.00}]
list4 = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'bat', 'price': 14.00}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'ball', 'price': 9.00}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'brick', 'price': 13.00}]
list...
```

I want a list of dicts in which the 'id' exists in all of the old lists:

```
result_list = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'bat}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'brick}]
```

The values that aren't constant for a given 'id' can be discarded, but the values that are the same for a given 'id' must be in the results list.

If I know how many lists I've got, I can do:

```
results_list = []
for dict in list1:
    if any(dict['id'] == d['id'] for d in list2):
        if any(dict['id'] == d['id'] for d in list3):
            if any(dict['id'] == d['id'] for d in list4):
                results_list.append(dict)
```

How can I do this if I don't know how many lists I've got?

Comment: I have updated my solution to correspond to your updated question.

Answer (score 5):

Put the `id`s into `set`s and then take the intersection of the `set`s.

```
list1 = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'steve'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'john'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'mary'}]
list2 = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'jake'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'tara'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'bill'}]
list3 = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'peter'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'rick'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'marci'}]
list4 = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'susan'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'evan'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'tom'}]
lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4]

sets = [set(x['id'] for x in lst) for lst in lists]
intersection = set.intersection(*sets)
print(intersection)
```

Result:

```
{1, 3}
```

Note that we call the class method `set.intersection` rather than the instance method `set().intersection`, since the latter takes intersections of its arguments with the empty set `set()`, and of course the intersection of anything with the empty set is empty.

If you want to turn this back into a list of dicts, you can do:

```
result = [{'id': i, 'name': None} for i in intersection]
print(result)
```

Result:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': None}, {'id': 3, 'name': None}]
```

---

Now, if you also want to hold onto those attributes which are the same for all instances of a given `id`, you'll want to do something like this:

```
list1 = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'bat', 'price': 20.00}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'ball', 'price': 12.00}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'brick', 'price': 19.00}]
list2 = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'bat', 'price': 18.00}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'brick', 'price': 11.00}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'ball', 'price': 17.00}]
list3 = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'bat', 'price': 16.00}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'boat', 'price': 10.00}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'brick', 'price': 15.00}]
list4 = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'bat', 'price': 14.00}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'ball', 'price': 9.00}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'brick', 'price': 13.00}]
lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4]

sets = [set(x['id'] for x in lst) for lst in lists]
intersection = set.intersection(*sets)

all_keys = set(lists[0][0].keys())
result = []
for ident in intersection:
    res = [dic for lst in lists
               for dic in lst
           if dic['id'] == ident]
    replicated_keys = []
    for key in all_keys:
        if len(set(dic[key] for dic in res)) == 1:
            replicated_keys.append(key)
    result.append({key: res[0][key] for key in replicated_keys})
print(result)
```

Result:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'bat'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'brick'}]
```

What we do here is:

- Look at each `id` in `intersection` and grab each dict corresponding to that `id`.
- Find which keys have the same value in all of those dicts (one of which is guaranteed to be `id`).
- Put those key-value pairs into `result`

This code assumes that:

- Each dict in `list1, list2, ...` will have the same keys. If this assumption is false, let me know - it shouldn't be difficult to relax.

Comment: What if I don't know how many lists I've got to start with?  how do I construct this? 


    'lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4, ...]'


Also, what if I have several key/value pairs in the dicts (which are constant for a given ID)...how can I build the result list with all of the values of the original dicts? Will I need to do a lookup of the k/v pair in intersection in an old list to build to results?

Comment: @user3205089 Where are your lists coming from? If you don't know how many of them there are, surely they must be inside some container data structure to begin with. For the rest of what you've just asked, please update your question with more information about what else you'd like to do with your data, in greater detail.

Comment: The actual lists of product results for different cities. I may have 1, I have have 7 lists of results.  I want to create a list of products that appear in all cities. product_id and name will be constant, merchant_id and price may not. I realize this is a much clearer example, I'll update my initial question.